# Restricted Weighted Linear Regression in R

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, weighted-regression, constrained-regression

I have to follwing issue. I would like to run a linear regression imposing a constraint on the weighted coefficients. Let me construct an example:

Consider the following cross-sectional regression

$r_{i} = \alpha + \beta_{1} x_{i,1} + \beta_{2}x_{i,2} + \gamma_{1} I_{i, 1} + \gamma_{2} I_{i, 2} + \gamma_{3} I_{i, 3} + \epsilon_{i}$

where $r_{i}$ is the return of stock $i$, $x_{i, 1}$ is a continuous variable (book-to-market ratio of a stock) and $I_{i,1}$ represents a dummy variable which is one if the company belongs to a certain industry and zero otherwise (here I have three industries). The regression should be a weighted linear regression, using the value weights of industry j in the value-weighted market, as weights. In R it would look something like this:

```
lm(r ~ x1 +  x2 + I1 + I2 + I3, weights = w, data = data)
```

Now I would like to constrain the regression such that the weighted coefficients for the dummies to add up to zero:

$\sum_{j=1}^{3} w_{j} \gamma_{j} = 0$

Does anyone know how I can achieve that in R?

If anyone is interested, I would like to reproduce the results of the paper:

Jose Menchero (2010) - Characteristics of Factor Portfolios

which relies on results of

Steven L. Heston, K. Geert Rouwenhorst (1994) - Does industrial structure explain the benefits of international diversification?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

This is what I did as an example but didn't work:

````
library(quadprog)

w <- c(0.1, 0.12, 0.08, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05, 0.14, 0.16, 0.04, 0.06) #weights
y <- rnorm(10) #returns
x1 <- rnorm(10) #continuous variable
x2 <- rnorm(10) #continuous variable
d1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) #dummy 1
d2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1) #dummy 2
d3 <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) #dummy 3

X = cbind(intercept = 1, x1, x2, d1 = d1, d2 = d2, d3 = d3)
W <- diag(w)

# solve the quadratic program
lmsol = solve.QP(Dmat = t(X) %*% W %*% X,
                           dvec = t(X) %*% W %*% y,
                           Amat = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 1, nrow = 6),
                           bvec = 0,
                           meq = 1)

lmsol$solution # estimates constrained coefficients
lmsol$unconstrained.solution # estimates unconstrained coefficients
```
````

Comment: Your reference to weights in `lm` is confusing, because those are *observation* weights, not variable weights, whereas elsewhere in this post you seem to be referring to *variable* weights.  Could you explain your meaning consistently?  I should also ask whether your question has any statistical component, because linear constraints on regression parameters are routinely treated in regression textbooks and implemented in software (including `R`).  Is it that you are familiar with the theory and just want to know the details of `R`, or do you want to know the theory?

Comment: That is exactly the issue. Let me try to clarify:

I would like to run the following weighted regression (using market capitalization as weights):

$r_{i} = \alpha + \beta_{1} x_{1} + \beta_{2} x_{2} + \gamma_{1} I_{i, 1} + \gamma{2} I_{i, 2} + \gamma_{3} I_{i,3} + \epsilon$ 

$x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are continuous and $I_{i,1}$ , $I_{i,2}$, $I_{i,3}$ dummies. Now the regression use market capitalization as observation weights. The dummies on the other hand should be weighted by the weight the respective industry has compared to the total market.

Comment: I tried to work around by pre multiplying the dummy with the observation weigth, so I do not have 1's and 0's but the respective industry weight in the dummy variable. If I run this constrained regression (quadprog), I get: 
```R 
Error in solve.QP(Dmat = t(mX) %*% W %*% mX, dvec = t(mX) %*% W %*% y,  : 
  matrix D in quadratic function is not positive definite!
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make any sense of this.  The $\gamma_i$ will *automatically* produce the proper weights for the regression.  Could you explain how you hope that industry weights could be used to modify the model?

Comment: Let me explain it in the words of the papers' authors:

The model is:

$r_{i} = f_{w} + \sum_{c}X_{ic}f_{c} + \sum_{j}X_{ij}f_{j} + \sum_{s}X_{is}f_{s} + u_{i}$.

The model uses regression weights proportional to the square root of market capitalization. $X_{ic}$ are continous variables (i.e. book-to-market-ratio of a stock}, $X_{ij}$ dummies for the industries and $X_{is}$ dummies for the country.

Then they use the following contraints...

Comment: ..."Since every stock belongs to a country and industry, the factor structure in the model contains two exact collinearities. In order to obtain a unique regression solution, we impose two constraints: the cap-weighted country factor returns sum to zero, and the cap-weighted industry factor returns sum to zero." Because I do not have a country factor in my case, I only need to impose the second one. That is just what I would like to do.

Comment: These are *observation* weights: apparently each observation is a "stock," among whose attributes are country and industry.  These attributes are used to assign weights to each stock, *not to the variables themselves.*  The description of constraints sounds exactly like a method of coding categorical variables and is necessary regardless of whether the regression is weighted.

Comment: So do you have a proposition how to achieve all that in R?

Comment: This is built into `lm`: see the manual page and read about the `weights` argument.

Comment: Yes, I know how to add weights to the regression, but what is about the constraint that the weighted coefficients of the dummies have to add to 0?

Comment: That sounds like the question you *should* be asking :-).

Comment: So should I ask a new question or can you answer it here?

Comment: Please just edit your post in this thread.

Comment: Okay, I did adjust it.